# How can I convert this data set into an object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to convert this data set into an object.

[image]

Intended outcome

```
let data = [
  {
    "Year Group": "Year Six",
    "Sunday": [Girl's football],
    "Monday": [No clubs on this day],
    "Tuesday": [Girls Netball] 
  },
  {
    "Year Group": "Year Five",
    "Sunday": [Boys football],
    "Monday": [No clubs on this day],
    "Tuesday": [Girls Netball]
}
]
```

This data will then be used to create a branching Google form. If there is a better object structure in order to achieve this, please do let me know.

Thank you,

For those that may need it. Following one of the answers, I realised it would be better if I had a situation where only the days unique to the year group were stored in the year group object.

Below is the adapted code based on one of the answers by 'TheWizEd'.

```
let values = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
    let data = [];
    values.shift();  // remove headers
    // create year groups
    let yearGroups = [...new Set(values.map( row => row[1] ))];
      
    yearGroups.forEach((group) => {
      let sorted = values.filter( row => row[1] ===  group )
      let days = [...new Set(sorted.map((row)=> row[4] ))]
      let dayBlankArray = days.map( day => [] )
      sorted.forEach((e)=>{
        let index = days.indexOf(e[4]);
        if( index >= 0 ) dayBlankArray[index].push(e[0]);
      })
      let object = { "Year Group": group };
      days.forEach((day,index)=> {
        object[day] = dayBlankArray[index]
        
      })
      data.push(object);
    })
    return data
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to sort and create groups by year.

**Code.gs**

```
function createGroups() {
  try {
    let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let data = [];
    values.shift();  // remove headers
    // create year groups
    let groups = [...new Set(values.map( row => row[1] ))];
    console.log("groups = "+groups)
    groups.forEach( group => {
        let activities = days.map( day => [] );
        // sort by group
        let sorted = values.filter( row => row[1] ===  group );
        // nest sort by day
        sorted.forEach( activity => {
            let index = days.indexOf(activity[4]);
            if( index >= 0 ) activities[index].push(activity[0]);
          }
        );
        // now construct the object
        let object = { "Year Group": group };
        let numDays = days.length;
        days.forEach( (day,index) => {
            if( activities[index].length === 0 ) {
              activities[index].push("No clubs on this day");
              numDays--;
            }
            object[day] = activities[index];
          }
        );
        object["Num Days"] = numDays;
        data.push(object);
      }
    );
    console.log(data);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
9:34:27 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:34:28 AM  Info    groups = Year Five,Year Six,Year Seven,Year One,Year Two
9:34:28 AM  Info    [ { 'Year Group': 'Year Five',
    Sunday: [ 'Girls Football', 'Boys Football' ],
    Monday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ],
    Tuesday: [ 'Girls Netball' ],
    Wednesday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ] },
  { 'Year Group': 'Year Six',
    Sunday: [ 'Girls Football' ],
    Monday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ],
    Tuesday: [ 'Girls Netball' ],
    Wednesday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ] },
  { 'Year Group': 'Year Seven',
    Sunday: [ 'Girls Football', 'Boys Football' ],
    Monday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ],
    Tuesday: [ 'Girls Netball' ],
    Wednesday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ] },
  { 'Year Group': 'Year One',
    Sunday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ],
    Monday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ],
    Tuesday: [ 'Multi Sports' ],
    Wednesday: [ 'Gymnastics' ] },
  { 'Year Group': 'Year Two',
    Sunday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ],
    Monday: [ 'No clubs on this day' ],
    Tuesday: [ 'Multi Sports' ],
    Wednesday: [ 'Gymnastics' ] } ]
9:34:28 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [[...new Set()]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Array.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Comment: absolutely sensational. I would never had got this myself, but I will learn from your solution that's for certain. Thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to store the number of days unique to a given year group? For instance, year one only has clubs on Tuesday and Wednesday.

Comment: I've updated my script to count the number of days with activity.

Comment: thank you but I can't see the changes to the code. I may be missing something though.

Comment: Oops, though I did it.  I changed this to be more flexible `let activities = days.map( day => [] );`, added this `let numDays = days.length;`, this `numDays--;` and this `object["Num Days"] = numDays;`.
`

Comment: thank you. However, for each year group it stills comes up with Sunday, Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday in the object. In a given year group, there may only be clubs on Monday or Tuesday. Those days should only exist in the end object. I believe it might be this line: let activities = days.map( day => [] ); because  let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"];

Comment: That’s not what you show in your OP.  You only want to show the days that have activity (I.e., 2 days)?

Comment: you are correct. My apologies. You have been very helpful!

Comment: using your code I managed to work out a solution. Thank you for the skeleton.